# How can I move to other user's Profile page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, show

I have a user that has some friends in his user list. How can i check their profile page? Where can I do that? I was doing it like this :

```
 % @accounts.each do |account| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to account.name, account %></td>
```

but I'm always moving to my current_account instead of the users I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

--EDITED--

This is my show class:

```
<%- model_class = Account -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
</div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dd><%= image_tag @account.profile_photo.url %></dd>
   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.name %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:gender) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.gender %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:age) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.age %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("Date Of Birth") %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= (@account.year_Of_Birth.to_s) +"/"+(@account.month_Of_Birth.to_s)+"/"+(@account.day_Of_Birth.to_s)  %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:country) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.country %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:favorite_Sport) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.favorite_Sport %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:account_id) %>:</strong></dt>

</dl>
```

Comment: is `account#show` scoped to the current user?

Comment: Yep it is current user, I don't know what to put there

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you provided, if you want other users to be able to view others profiles page you can't scope `#show` to the current user.  Instead do something like this:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @account = Account.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

Comment: I just edited my post with the show view. Now I'm getting this error undefined method `profile_photo' for nil:NilClass

Comment: sounds like a different error - you're better off to open another question.